# How to test using Jest

Tags: jestjs

I am new to Jest. Looking Jest as a unit testing framework, How can it be used for testing a website. I could found Jest examples applies to validation of Java script business functionalities but how can it be used for a website testing similar to Selenium.  It would be really great if somebody could  provide an update.

Thanks in Advance.

gtlkanth

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using an http mocking library like `nock` to simulate http requests, and then using enzyme to simulate click and the like and then Jest as your assertion library.

Answer (score 1):

Jest can't be used for end to end integration tests. It is focused on testing isolated features of your application's logic.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/560